# Type hinting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ide, type-hinting

In PHP, I remember it was possible to do this (this is using Symfony2):

```
use AppBundle\Entity\AccountUser;

/** @var AccountUser $user */
$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:AccountUser')

$user-> ...hints...
```

And the IDE would recognise `$user` as an `AccountUser` object and pull information through for typehinting.

Is this possible in Javascript too? I'm thinking for dependencies from the `node_modules` folder more specifically:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

/**
 * @type {Object} DocumentClient
 */
const db = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

db. ...hints...
```

Comment: You're pretty much looking for TypeScript?

Comment: Well my client's system is written in just Javascript, so I was wondering if there was a way of getting Webstorm to recognise the type of external dependencies, because it predicts methods correctly for a lot of objects (but not others), but I'm not sure I completely understand what is going on behind the scenes or what I need to search for to read up on.

Comment: [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/), specifically the [type hinting tags](https://devhints.io/jsdoc).  [Type Safe JavaScript with JSDoc](https://medium.com/@trukrs/type-safe-javascript-with-jsdoc-7a2a63209b76) looks like a good read with examples. I'm not working with npm modules, so not sure how you get those recognized - ask in a forum for whatever IDE you prefer.

Comment: Seeing this pop up again 2 years later, and @deceze, yes Typescript is what I now realise I needed!